# Having IE Issues When Passing Object By Ref. and Dynamically Adding Properties

Tags: javascript, object, reference

So, I've created a function to do some error checking on an XML file that I recieve from an AJAX call. Part of the validation is that the function then builds out an object for easy access while I process that data into a form. In FF, works like a charm. IE dies with the error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Here is the function (minus the un-important bits):

```
function checkReceiveXMLTagString( doc, messageObject, tag ) {

    var tag_nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName( tag );

    ...do some error checking...

    messageObject[tag] = tag_str; <-- error occurs on this line

    return true;
}
```

Here is an example of how the function is call:

```
if ( checkReceiveXMLTagString( messageObject.Name[0], messageObject.Name[0], "First" ) ) {

    ...process messageObject.Name[0].First...

}
```

Like I said, FF has no issues. Safari loads the pages as well. IE has issues.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to show us exactly what the `messageObject` parameter is as passed to `checkReceiveXMLTagString()` for us to do anything other than guess.  The answer lies in what the data is which you have not disclosed to us.

Comment: If you want to see the site in action, here it is...

    http://cmccausegroups.com/

You can see an example XML response here:

    http://cmccausegroups.com/common/ajax/get_cause.php?cause=2

I'm working on it right now, so expect some funny stuff if you dare look at the live stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something is making `messageObject` be `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

If the error is on this line:

```
messageObject[tag] = tag_str;
```

Then, the only two ways I know of that that can cause an error are:

1. `messageObject` is not an object that you can set properties on (`null` or `undefined` are the most likely ways that would happen)
2. `tag` is null or undefined

Since I see that your code calls this function hundreds of times so you can't effectively just break on it, I'd suggest you put in some defensive coding to check for those conditions and output something to the debug console to identify what the state is when the problem occurs.  You can even trigger a conditional breakpoint with code like this:

```
if (!messageObject || !tag) {
    debugger;
}
```

In the toughest cases, you can put an exception handler around it and break when the exception is thrown:

```
try {
    messageObject[tag] = tag_str;
} catch(e) {
    debugger;
}
```

Both of these will allow you to capture the condition in the debugger and examine all your parameters at the time of the error.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why IE would say these variables are null or do not exist when FF has no problem with them. Stepping through everything with Firebug results in everything I would expect. Whereas I feel like IE thinks that adding the array value of the new tag to the messageObject is trying to access something that should already be there. What are the best IE JS debugging tools out there?

Comment: With IE9, I think the Developer Tools are just built in (that's what I use).  Just hit F12.  For some earlier versions of IE, it may take an extra download.  If you don't already have it with F12, then Google "internet explorer developer tools" and look up your version of IE.

Comment: Don't be so surprised that something works differently in one browser vs. the other.  You probably stepped on either a bug or a feature that works differently in the two browsers.  Browser development is about coding, testing, debugging and learning how to find and then avoid cross browser differences.

Comment: Understood. This is the first major issue that I haven't found a work around in 6 months. The funny thing is that both Firebug and Microsoft Script editor both show the EXACT same data up until the error. Whereas Firefox will dynamically create the object property, IE goes strait to an "undefined" error...I'll have to play with somehow declaring the property before it gets called in the function and hopefully get past this. I thought MS CSS was hard to debug...this is just silly. Hopefully I can find a work-around without having to re-write it all or have someone who has come across this help.

Comment: Did you try catching the exception and dropping into the debugger to see why it makes the error?  IE doesn't need an attribute pre-created in order to assign it so there's something else going on here.

Comment: Give me a version of the page that catches the exception and drops into the debugger and I'll take a look.  That function is called a zillion times so I can't step through and catch the error.  I promise you there's something wrong with one of your objects/variables.  No property needs to be pre-created before assigning to it.

Comment: actually...i just figured it out. wow. strange. I can't use the same Object for each function to continue to build it up to a single data structure. I had to create a unique singular object for every "set" of tags I broke down. This is really weird...

Comment: ...and I just re-wrote it using the jQuery XML parser. Took 1/10th the time. Didn't know it was that simple and I have the ability to keep everything just as secure with all my error checking. Thanks for all your help everyone!